# jdbc ucanaccesssqlexception ucaexc ::: 4.0 4 unexpected token: DOCTOR

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am using netbeans with java classes to fetch data from access database tables and display it on jtable. When I followed all the steps it gives me the ucanaccess error as net ucanaccess jdbc ucanaccesssqlexception ucaexc ::: 4.0 4 unexpected token: DOCTOR. i have two tables in accdb called Patient and Doctor.

I have done everything needed for it.

```
public void viewAppointment() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{    
   Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");     
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/AQ/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MC170402106_2/MC170402106.accdb");     
   String sql1 = "Select p.Name AS Patient, p.Disesae AS Disease, Doctor.Name AS Doctor"
           + " Doctor.Visiting_Day AS SechduleDay from Patients AS p"
           + " where p.Disease = Doctor.Specialization";     
   try{     
       ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);     
       rs = ps.executeQuery();      
       jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));     
   }          
   catch(Exception e){         
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);       
   }
```

I expect that this will take data from database and display it on jtable.

Comment: You have a typo, the prefix of the URL should be **`jdbc:ucanaccess:`**, not `jdbc.ucanaccess:` (use **`:`** instead of a `.`).

Comment: What's the point of the `Class.forName` statement? It's not needed.

Comment: now it giving " net ucanaccess jdbc ucanaccesssqlexception ucaexc ::: 4.0 4 unexpected token: DOCTOR "

Comment: `Class.forName()` was a way of loading drivers prior to JDBC 4, I think. So it's possible that old learning material still puts it in just to make sure and avoid potential issues.

Comment: The FROM criteria is missing the query to Doctor table. Dont forget the 'link' (FK relation) between Doctor and Patient in WHERE criteria (p.Disease = Doctor.Specialization may not be enough)

Comment: You are missing a comma after `Doctor.Name AS Doctor`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume:

1. you are using JPA
2. you set `delimited-identifiers`
3. you also are using EclipseLink as implementation.

If so, do as follows:

Include a target-database entry in persistence.xml:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig"/>
```

Add a new class to your classpath:

```
package org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database;

public class AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig extends AccessPlatform {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7034590043310425678L;

    public AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig() {
        super();
        this.tableQualifier = "";
        this.startDelimiter = "";
        this.endDelimiter = "";
    }
}
```